# Configuring junitxml output for specs2 tests in sbt 0.10

Tags: scala, sbt, specs2

How do I configure sbt 0.10 to use the junitxml option with specs2?

The [specs2 documentation](http://etorreborre.github.com/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.Runners.html#Simple+build+tool) says this is the way to do it using sbt 0.7.x:

`override def testOptions = super.testOptions ++ Seq(TestArgument("junitxml"))`

How do I say the same thing in sbt 0.10?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is described [here](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Testing) in the SBT documentation:

```
testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument("junitxml")
```

And if you want to specify this option specifically for specs2:

```
testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.Specs2, "junitxml")
```

Answer (score 11):

FYI, I found that when running Specs2 tests with juntxml SBT fails to fail when the tests fail.  Adding "console" as another argument gets a build failure like you'd expect.  I suspect this is some interaction between the console reporter and sbt's test driver.

> testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.Specs2, "junitxml", "console")